# Fatal exception by startActivity

Tags: android

I have two Activiti (Smena and Sdacha)
I push the button on Smena and opening Sdacha.
I need send String from textView Sdacha to Smena.
When I push the button on Sdacha I get ERROR

```
public class Sdacha extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sdacha);    

        Button but10=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        but10.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        Intent intent1=new Intent(Sdacha.this,Smena.class);

                             startActivity(intent1);
                    }
            });

    }
}
```

>

```
 12-25 18:05:40.130: WARN/dalvikvm(378): threadid=1: thread exiting
> with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760) 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity ComponentInfo{com.example.master/com.example.master.Smena}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-25 18:05:40.151:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> com.example.hotdog_master.Smena.onCreate(Smena.java:42) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397) 12-25
> 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
> 12-25 18:05:40.151: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     ... 11 more
```

Smena Activiti it is activity for cashier
Smena Activity code:

```
public class Smena extends Activity 
{
    public Nomenklatura Asortiment=new Nomenklatura(100);
    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "myLogs";
    ArrayList<String> data =new ArrayList<String> ();
    ArrayList<String> data2 =new ArrayList<String> (4);
    GridView gvMain;
    GridView gvMain2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    double Sum=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smena); 
        Asortiment=(Nomenklatura) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Nomenklatura");

        data2.add("СУММА");
        data2.add("0");
        data2.add("СДАЧА");
        data2.add("0");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
        gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item2, R.id.tvText, data2);
        gvMain2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gvMain2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but1.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        ButtonOn (1);
                    }
            });
        Button but21=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        but21.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        ButtonDel();
                    }
            });

        Button but22=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
        but22.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        data.clear();
                        adapter.clear();

                    }
            });

        Button but23=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
        but23.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        Intent intent1=new Intent(Smena.this,Login.class);
                        // intent1.putExtra("Sdacha", Asortiment);
                         startActivity(intent1);

                    }
            });
    }
    private void ButtonDel()
    {
        int cnt=    data.size();
        data.remove(cnt-1);
        data.remove(cnt-2);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void ButtonOn (int Art)
    {
        String name=    Asortiment.name.get(1);
        String price=   Asortiment.price.get(1).toString();
        data.add(name);
        data.add(price);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
    private void CheckSum()
    {
        Sum=0;
        for(int k=1;k<data.size();k=k+2)
        {
            Sum=Sum+Double.parseDouble(data.get(k));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post Smena activity code also because issue is in Smena Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check these things if defined and declared correctly:

1) If all the id's are correct according to the corresponding XML's.

2) The activities are defined in the Manifest file.

3) Check the line number 42 in the Smena Activity for the error.

Try out and let me know. If possible include the codes of these files for further explore.

Comment: Error was on line 42, I try to get extras from intent, which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Pls try as such

```
  startActivity(new Intent(this,Smena.class));
```

Comment: Hmm, would not work since `this` is the `OnClickListener` instance.